# Is there an easy way to thread or multiprocess a non-intensive function?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, subprocess

I'm self-learning python so I don't know how to describe this in a way that would be clear, so here's the easiest by proxy example I can come up with in pseudo code:

```
#where r() is a random number function
objCount = 0
def mainfunc()
  while playgame= True and objCount < 100:
    create(r(time))
    time.sleep(1)
  return None

def create(tmptime)
  global objCount
  objCount = objCount+1
  newobj = plotSomething(r(x),r(y))
  time.sleep(tmptime)
  selfDelete..
  return None

mainfunc() #run it
```

Instead of it making a random "lived" object every second, it makes a random lived object every second, but waits for it's "life" to expire. I'm trying to just fire this thing off to a sidechain to timeout on its own while still making new things.

All the documentation is getting super involved using asyncio, multithreading, *etc.*

Is there an easy way to kick this thing out of the main loop and not hold up traffic?

Comment: I don't know what a non-intensive function is but you can use `concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor` which has a fairly easy api for kicking off tasks and checking on their status.

Comment: the closest i've found is to use ".start()" on the create function in the loop?

Comment: non intensive is really does nothing much but eat clock cycles..

I thought about having another function call in the main loop to cycle a list of the created with a tuple style link between the expiration time and the obj identifier, but that gets all sorts of loop intensive, list editing intensive while things are added and removed by decrementing the tuple times until zero and deleting from the global list

Comment: The official python docs have a nice example of how to use the `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

Answer (score 0):

laziest method for simplicity is :

```
import concurrent.futures as delayobj
#where r() is a random number function
objCount = 0
def mainfunc()
  global objCount
  with delayobj:
    while objCount < 100:
      delayobj.ThreapoolExecutor().submit(create,tmptime=r(time))
      time.sleep(1)
  return None

def create(tmptime)
  global objCount
  objCount = objCount+1
  newobj = plotSomething(r(x),r(y))
  time.sleep(tmptime)
  selfDelete..
  return None

mainfunc() #run it
```

thanks again guys

Comment: You have some issues here. You cannot use *delayobj* like that (context manager). You almost certainly do not want to send *time* to your *r* function. You have several syntax errors. You probably **do** need to learn some fundamentals of Python before delving into the complexities of multi-threading